# Bash curl call second command only when status is not 200

Tags: bash, curl

I looking for solution how combine two curl request in bash, and call second curl only when first doesnt return status 200.

I tried:

```
curl -s "https://example.com/first" || curl -s "https://example.com/second"
```

but it still call both because first curl is successful if return for example status 404.

How it is possible call second only when first doesnt return status 200?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`curl -s -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code}" https://example.com | grep -q "^200$" || curl -s https://example.com/2.html`

Edit: added improvement by @tripleee to not pollute output with grep output.

Comment: You want `grep -q` and `&&`

Comment: But the question was "How it is possible call **second only when first doesnt return status 200**"?